# Изменение файлов на heroku

Tags: python, heroku

Залил бота под дискорд на heroku, хранил некоторые данные в pickle(а потом пытался и просто в .py) и по ходу программы значения в нём менялись(мне их нужно сохранять и дальше с ними работать). При рестарте heroku(автоматическом или ручном) все эти значения сбрасывались на стандартные (которые были в изначально задеплоенном файле). Как можно этого избежать?

Comment: Попробуйте все нужные данные записывать в файл конфига. https://habr.com/ru/post/485236/

Comment: может ты не делал `file.close()`?

Comment: @FotonPC закрывал. На локалке работало. Просто, как я понял, после каждого рестарта heroku скачивает заново файлы с репозитория на который я деплоил, и во время работы изменяются лишь локальные файлы. После рестарта они переписываются

Comment: @DGDays, уже записываю но в исходный код, попробую посмотреть

Comment: @DGDays, не решает проблему перезаписывания файлов к сожалению :(

Comment: Хм... Никогда не использовал `heroku`, но может есть возможность делать запись на саму репу?

Comment: @DGDays, может и есть, вот ищу помощи, ибо сам найти не смог :(

Comment: @DGDays, придётся коннектить через sql или postgresql

Comment: @Sanlover, пробовал: https://coderoad.ru/21465789/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-Heroku-bash ?

Comment: @Sanlover, вы сказали, что файлы переписываются _чистыми_ из репозитория. А если убрать пустой файл из репозитория и создавать его во время работы программы?

Comment: @DGDays Решил проблему по другому. Просто подключил heroku-postgresql, и работаю напряму с бд.

Comment: @viilpe, решил по другому, спасибо за идею, как-нибудь попробую